# RequireConfirmedAccount false and email confirmation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity

I am using ASP.NET Core Identity with `RequireConfirmedAccount = false`. The `true` option is too inconvenient for users because they cannot see the email confirmation page to resend the email token in case they did not receive it.

How can I enforce redirecting authenticated users with an UNCONFIRMED email to the email confirmation page?

My first thought was to write a custom middleware that checks if the user is authenticated (`SignInManager.IsSignedIn`) but with an unconfirmed email (`UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync`), and force redirects them to the email confirmation page on all routes. This way they cannot access anything except the email confirmation page, forcing them to confirm the email or resend the confirmation link.

However, I am (almost) sure that this scenario should be covered by the ASP.NET Core Identity in some way.

One way I imagine would be an option on `ConfigureApplicationCookie` like `LoginPath` but `EmailConfirmationPath` that force redirects users to this path if their email is not confirmed, but clearly there is no such option.

So how is it usually handled with Identity?

Answer (score 1):

With the build in Authentication& Authorization ,you could let it succeed Authentication but fail authorization ,set the AccessDeniedPath yourself,for example:

```
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(o => {
    
    o.Events.OnSignedIn =async ( context) =>    
    {       
        var usermanager = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<UserManager<AppUser>>();
        var user = await usermanager.FindByNameAsync(context.Principal.Identity.Name);
        if (user.EmailConfirmed)
        {
            var claim = new Claim("EmailConfirmed", "Confirmed");
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>() { claim });
            context.Principal.AddIdentity(identity);           
        }
        else
        {
            //options is registed as scoped here,so you could modify it for current request
            //don't set it gobally for we just want the accessdenied path be modified for current policy
            context.Options.AccessDeniedPath= "/Identity/Account/ResendEmailConfirmation";
        }
       
    };
});
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(x =>
{    
    x.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", p => p.RequireClaim("EmailConfirmed", "Confirmed"));
});
//apply the policy to the pages you want to protect
app.MapRazorPages().RequireAuthorization("MyPolicy");
```

Result:

[image]